# Why are the zeros of $f$ isolated?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 79 he proved the following theorem:

[image]

I think the theorem he is mentioning is a corollary which says  that each zero of $f$ has a finite multiplicity. I didn't understand why this implies the zeros of $f$ are isolated.

Comment: show that there is a finite number of zeros (counting multiplicity) in any finite region, for example by integrating $f'(z)/f(z)$ on a contour enclosing the region (contour on which $f(z) \ne 0$ ).

Comment: I don't know what "above theorem" is, but this is a consequence of Identity Theorem. If zeroes are not isolated in $G$ then it follows that $f=0$ identically

Comment: Isolated means : the set of zeros of f is a (topologically) discrete set. Around each zero there is a open ball such that there are no other zeros in that ball.

Answer (score 3):

We say a function $f$ has a zero of multiplicity $n$ at $z=a$ if $f$ can be written as $f(z)=(z-a)^{n}g(z)$ for some holomorphic function $g$ such that $g(a)\neq0$. By holomorphicity of $g$, there exists an $R$ such that $g(z) \neq 0$ in $|z-a|<R$. It follows directly that $f(z) \neq 0$ in $0<|z-a|<R$.

Answer (score 1):

since f is analytic, we have
$$f(z) = f(a) + \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(i)}(a)}{i!}(x-a)^i$$

from what you quoted corollary, f has finite multiplicity at a, so we assume k be the multiplcity. so f(a) = 0, ... $f^{k-1}(a) = 0$, and $f^{(k)}(a) \ne 0$ so we have
$$f(z) = \sum_{i =k}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(i)}(a)}{i!}(x-a)^i$$ is not zero for some R such that $0\le |z-a|\le R$ from this expansion.

Answer (score 0):

If the set of zeros of $f$ would have an accumulation point, it would immideatly follow from the identity theorem that $f=0$.