# A question about the proof of Hurwitz Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

It might be a really subtle point but I could not see why there is a $C$ centered at z with $f(z)\neq0$ on $C$. Any help would be appreciated! thanks

Comment: The zeros of analytic functions are *isolated.*

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1642597/42969